# Pick one item of each type with highest value without exceeding budget

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Given the list of items below, a budget B and a list of item types (T1, T2, T3...TN), pick 1 item of each type that provides the most value (most expensive) without exceeding the budget.

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "types": "T1",
    "price": 1000,
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "types": "T2",
    "price": 109292,
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "types": "T3",
    "price": 7228,
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "types": "T4",
    "price": 1000,
  },
]
```

Explored knapsack problems and not sure if this is a NP-complete problem.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: So, your array can have multiple items of same `type` with differents `id` and `price` and you want a list of they related to a given list of types `(t1, t2, ..., tn)` whose sum of prices are more closest to the **budget** limit?

Comment: This could help you on your way down: https://gist.github.com/danwoods/7496329

Comment: Yes. Pick items from the dataset list whose sum of prices are more closest to the budget limit. Items must be of unique type. You are given a list of types to pick and this list is a subset of the types in your dataset list

Comment: @MatthewHerbst The question is what is a recommended algorithm to solve this. Keep in mind that:
- The budget has be shared amongst all the item types
- You want to pick the item with the highest price from each type and not exceed your budget

Answer (score 1):

Just use `filter` to find all items that do not exceed budget, then `sort` it in descending order and take the first element:

```js
const array = [{
    "id": "1",
    "types": "T1",
    "price": 1000,
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "types": "T2",
    "price": 109292,
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "types": "T3",
    "price": 7228,
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "types": "T4",
    "price": 1000,
  },
];

const budget = 9000;

var budgetMatch = array.filter(({ price }) => price <= budget);
budgetMatch.sort(({ price: a}, { price: b}) => b - a);

var highestPrice = budgetMatch[0];

console.log(highestPrice);
```

Comment: This is good! This can help me pick the highest priced item that does not exceed the budget from the list and from a sub-list of type T. However, it does not consider that we want to pick one item from each type so that the some of the total items from all the picked types does not exceed our budget.

Again:
Given types T1, T2, T2 and Budget 9000, pick one item of type T1, T2, T2 such that the sum of the price of picked items does not exceed the budget